# Search bar for HTML files in a folder or from links in XML file

Tags: php, xml, html

I have a folder with about 2900 HTML files.

I want a search bar on my homepage that I can use to search this folder, to easy find and view the html file you search for.

I am currently trying to have the links in a xml file and search for them.

I have this code right now that works but it is extremely slow. Any suggestions how to make it more functional?

This is my index.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
<div id="livesearch"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My search.php file:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("table_of_content.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

This is how the XML document looks like. I only added one link here but it's about 2900 in total like this in the XML document:

```
<pages>
<link>
<title>TITLE</title>
<url>URL</url>
</link>
</pages>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! what have you tried so far? Some suggestion: used `scandir()` function and `glob()` function

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Jon Skeet's SO Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: edited my post with the code I try to base this search upon

Comment: @Sanguinary I updated it again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `scandir` function of PHP

```
<?php
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);

print_r($files1);
print_r($files2);
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => foo.txt
    [4] => somedir
)
Array
(
    [0] => somedir
    [1] => foo.txt
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => ..
    [4] => .
)
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

**Warning!!!** This example could be vulnerable to path traversal when you use dynamic user-input. Please **check, check and double check** the input beforce proceeding to this script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `opendir` and `readdir` for this kind of purpose.

```
<?php
$dir = "/your_folder_here/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if($file == $_POST['SEARCHBOX_INPUT']){
                echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Remember to change your file path. Also change the `$_POST` command in the middle to whatever the name of your search box input is. This will find **only** exact matches of your search. Changes could be made to find close matches for a better user experience.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try a simple form, that will trigger a php function
This is the **bare basic**, it's important to add security layers (preventing from any search to run, etc)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
 $dir = array();
 $dir = scandir('/tmp');
 $result = array_search($_POST['search'],$dir);
}

$output =<<<OUT
<html>
<form action="test.php" type="POST">
<input name="search" type="text" />
</form>
<p>result: {$result}</p>
</html>
OUT;

echo $output;
?>
```